# Are there any practical applications of the directrix of a parabola?

Tags: geometry, applications, conic-sections

I know of many applications for the focus of a parabola (satellite dish, whispering gallery, etc.), but haven't been able to find any for the directrix. An internet search has come up empty. I have interviewed several math teachers and none of them could help either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can always make up a real-world application...

Say you are walking along a parabola-shaped path, when you see a bear at the focus.  If all other bears are on the other side of the directrix, then you are safe.  But if there is a second bear on this side of the directrix, then watch out, because then your path will sometimes be nearer one bear and sometimes nearer the other, and when you get near this territorial boundary the bears will charge towards you to maintain their claim to you as food.

If you want to simulate a "point" reflector, that reflects waves aimed at the point directly back to their source, then might think you could use a mirrored ball centered at the point.  But this has the problem that the waves arrive back at the source before they should.  To solve this, you can instead use the outside of a parabola together with a mirror on the directrix.

Say there is a parabola-shaped lake, and you want to build two perpendicular roads, neither of which is blocked by the lake.  Where can the crossroads be?  Answer:  Anywhere on the far side of the directrix.

By the way, the two applications you mention for the focus are actually the same, since satellites are so far away that their faint signal needs to be collected in the same way as a whisper.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is really not a great answer. I could easily put a parallel road between the directrix and the vertex. And the bear thing is just completely manufactured. I believe both of us are looking for a real world USE of the directrix. Not something contrived.

Comment: @BSD The answer didn't say anything about a parallel road. You should read it more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

**The directrix represents the energy of a parabolic trajectory.**

If you throw a ball, then (ignoring air resistance) it will have a parabolic trajectory.  The directrix of this parabola is a horizontal line, the set of all points at a certain height in the parabola's plane. This height is the energy in the ball.  In other words, the potential energy that the ball would have if it were at rest at that height equals the potential plus kinetic energy of the ball everywhere on its parabolic path.

So if the ball has elastic collisions with fixed objects (walls, tables, or even oddly shaped objects), it will have a different parabolic trajectory after each bounce, but the directrix will always be at the same height as before.  In fact, the common height of these directrices is the maximum height that the ball can reach.

If the ball was dropped from a certain height, then you can figure out what that height was, even several bounces later: it is always the height of the directrix of its current parabolic trajectory.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. It is true that (assuming all collisions are elastic and no energy is lost) the ball's new parabolic trajectory would have the same directrix, but the directrix does not relate to energy. There is nothing about the vertical axis in meters that can be used to describe energy. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BSD The vertical axis in meters most certainly relates to the potential energy of the ball. As the answer says, the energy of the ball in motion always equals the potential energy the ball would have at the height of the directrix.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you're looking for, but here is a problem I've seen in a Calculus class.  It doesn't really have a real-world application (that I know of), but the directrix does come up in an interesting way.

> Let $S$ be the square with vertices $(-1,-1), (1,-1), (1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ (the square of side length 2 centered at the origin), and let $A$ be the set of all points closer to the origin than to the sides of $S$.  Find the area of $A$.

The boundary of $A$ is the set of all points whose distance to the origin equals the distance to one of the sides of the square.  Essentially $A$ is the region bounded by the four parabolas with focus at the origin and a side of the square as directrix.

Comment: I am in fact looking for real-world applications. I do appreciate the problem though. It requires using the locus definition of a parabola to solve. It's not real-world, but it is "an application". Thanks.