# Significance and applications of directrix of a conic

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, mathematical-physics

Focus point of a conic like parabola,ellipse has so much of significance in its applications such as satellite dishes or whisper gallery that this is the point where rays are converged enabling their functionality. Like this does directrix has any role in its applications otherthan using it for construction of conic.

Comment: At what level you want your answer to be?

Comment: The level more you give, the level more i dig to get more knowledge.Right now i am analyzing Dandalin spheres to get more insights into how all components of a conic section fit together in double napped right circular cone.

Comment: Duplicate, original question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33862/are-there-any-practical-applications-of-the-directrix-of-a-parabola

Comment: I knew there is a similar question asked but the answers are not clear, may be because of that there is no approved answer for it.